# How make a gradient plot in R from a matrix data stored in a .csv file?

Tags: r, csv, matrix, heatmap

I have a `xyz` matrix stored in a `.csv` file that, for example, looks like the following:

```
   1  2  3  4
1  1  1 -1  1
2 -1  1  1  1
3  1 -1  1 -1
4  1  1 -1  1
```

where the rows are `x`, columns are `y` and entries are `z`. I could store this matrix in a `dataframe`.

I want to create a `heatmap` of this matrix, where the entries would just be two colors, depending on `1` or `-1`. The plot would look like the following for an `18 X 18` matrix (done by a colleague in `matlab` probably):

where, say, yellow is for `1` and blue for `-1`.

How can I do this in `R`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `geom_tile()`. First you need to flatten your dataframe using `melt` from the package `reshape2`.

```
library(reshape2)
flat_df <- melt(t(df), value.name = "Value")
ggplot(data=flat_df,aes(y=y,x=x))+geom_tile(aes(fill=Value))+scale_y_reverse()
```

[image: Output from above code]

Answer (score 1):

Multiple ways, but a base way is to use `image()`.  Starting with a matrix:

```
# Matrix needs to be rotated 90 degrees before plotting with image()
m <- t(m[nrow(m):1, ])
image(m, axes = FALSE, col = c("navyblue", "yellow"))
axis(2, at = seq(0, 1, length.out = nrow(m)), labels = rev(seq(nrow(m))), las = 1, tcl = 0.5)
axis(1, at = seq(0, 1, length.out = ncol(m)), labels = seq(ncol(m)), tcl = 0.5)
box()
```

[image]

Data:

```
txt <- "1  1 -1  1
-1  1  1  1
1 -1  1 -1
1  1 -1  1"

m <- matrix(scan(text = txt, quiet = TRUE), byrow = TRUE, nrow = 4, dimnames =  list(1:4, 1:4))
```